# Does rclpy supports intraprocess communication?

Tags: publisher, topic, communication, subscribe, rclpy

I wanted to know if rclpy supports intraprocess communication or is there a way to do intraprocess in rclpy with python based libraries?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe someone with more experience with it could comment but I wonder if zenoh python suits your needs (https://github.com/eclipse-zenoh/zenoh-python) - you would be using zenoh directly using ros messages but using zenoh pub/sub, not ros pub/sub (but no shared memory in zenoh python? https://github.com/eclipse-zenoh/zenoh-python/issues/33).  Eventually with ros2 jazzy rclpy will be capable of using zenoh under the hood anyhow.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it might be useful at first glance.